# How to force flashdevelop to recompile classes?

Tags: flashdevelop

I am working on someone else code in FlashDevelop.

// in Page.as class

```
for each(o in data.zones) { _overlays.push(Skin.instance.setOverlay(_cOverlay, o)); }
```

// in Overlay.as Class

```
public function init(data:Object):void {
trace("hello world");
...
```

Problem is.. hello world is NOT DISPLAYED, but another OLD trace message: 
It seems like FLashDevelop does not re-compile Overlay.as !

When I use debugger, it goes inside Overlay.as, go thorugh trace("hello world"); but outputs something else instead !

**It looks like FlashDevelop keeps cache of the old Overlay.as compiled version instead: how can I force to recompile all ?**

regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Flashdevelop recompiles code when it's changed, so changing

`trace("hello world");` to `trace("hello world!");`

should recompile the code.

If this doesn't fix it, I'll recommend looking through Overlay.as to check if `init` is actually called.